# how to create a custom layout in sublime text 2?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

I would like to create a 2 column layout where column 2 is split into 2 rows but havent really had any joy trying to find out how this can be done. I know that this layout gets added to Main.sublime-menu so I duplicated one of the layouts and called it Custom 1, not sure what I have to add in as the key/value pairs or array though. Could anyone possibly help me with this?

here is what im working with so far:

```
{
                        "caption": "Custom 1",
                        "command": "set_layout",
                        "args":
                        {
                            "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
                            "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
                            "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1, 3]]
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
    "caption" : "Custom 1",
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "cells":
        [
            [0, 0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 1],
                          [1, 1, 2, 2]
        ]
    }
}
```

Reference:

- https://gist.github.com/1320281

Comment: Sublime Text n00b here. 1. Is this script for ST in Windows too or only Mac? 2. Where do you save this code? I tried in Preferences.sublime-settings but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @ricardozea 1. It should works in all platforms (i tested it in Ubuntu) 2. I saved it in a "Main.sublime-menu" file. Look for an example in your Packages directory. Regards

Comment: @aanton Thanks for the info, I'll give that a try. Also, I used this ST plugin as well, Origami: https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami.

Answer (score 4):

This structure helps you to make yourself any design in Sublime Text.

```
         0.0                             0.5                           1.0
          +-------------------------------+-----------------------------+

         0,0                             1,0                           2,0
   0.0    +-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |   0,1                              1,1                           2,1
  0.33    |                               +-----------------------------+
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |   0,2                              1,2                           2,2
  0.66    |                               +-----------------------------+
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |    |                               |                             |
     |   0,3                             1,3                           2,3
   1.0    +-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

http://asciiflow.com/#0B0pB9AbvJ9zLcHFZYnp2YTZjNU0

---

**Sublime View:** (2 column, 1 column split into 3 row)

[image]

Your keymap Setting (*Preferences -> Key Binding User -> Add inside brackets*)

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+7"],
    "caption": "2 cols (full - 3)",
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
        { "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
          "rows": [0.0, 0.33, 0.66, 1.0],
          "cells": [ [0, 0, 1, 3], [1, 0, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3] ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to have a two row layout, where the first row contains one panel (one column) while the second row contains two columns, use this code:

```
{
    "caption": "1. Full - 2. 2 columns",
    "command": "set_layout",
    "args":
    {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "cells":
        [
            [0, 0, 2, 1], 
            [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the awesome [sublime-SplitScreen](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-SplitScreen) plugin.

- install via package control: `Cmd+Shift+P`, then install package and search for "SplitScreen".

  - `Cmd` in Mac, `Ctrl` otherwise.
- After installing, `Alt+Shift+S` to activate the plugin, and enter a ration like `7:3,2:1` to achieve this layout:

```
--------------------
|             |    |
|             |    |
|             |    |
|             |    |
--------------------
|             |    |
|             |    |
--------------------
```

- More examples in the project's readme.