# Sublime 2 - multiple uneven panes

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I want to split the screen in sublime unevenly.
for example, split vertically to 2 panes, where the top pane is split to two horizontal panes (3 panes in total, two in the top and one in the bottom).

I know the `Shift+Alt+<NUM>` thing, but I only managed to split evenly with it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create a custom layout in sublime text 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913138/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the following in the ST console (View menu -> Show Console) to get a split layout with 2 panes on the top row and 1 pane in the bottom row:

```
window.run_command('set_layout', {"cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 2, 2]], "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0], "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]})
```

here is how it looks in ST3:

[image: ST3 layout]

with thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30408703/4473405 / https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/set-layout-reference/5713 for explaining how the cells layout works

Comment: thanks for the answer. I actually just saw it after you gave the reference. I was just wondering whether there's a more convenient way to do it. I want to be able to work fast with it, while being flexible with the number of panes I use...

Comment: You might like the Origami package; it provides a convenient way to work with panes dynamically: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Origami